# GPS accuracy circle (in meters) intersects a line on map

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, latitude-longitude

I'm drawing a point which reflects my current location. I've got some shapes on the map as well. However, due to changing GPS accuracy I need to show that I've crossed the line on map even if a LatLng point is still before it but the accuracy is ~20(m). 
What I have:
 - line's start and end points
 - circle's center
 - circle's radius (in meters)

I'm able to calculate the distance between line and circle's center point but that gives me the value like: 0.00987506668990474 which gives me really nothing because this value does not reflect the distance in meters and I can't really convert that to meters and compare with accuracy radius. 
I'm not even sure if I'm on good target to get that information. Maybe there's some another method to get the information if there's an intersection or not.

thanks for any hints

update:
using the distance * 110km I'm getting much better results. 
[image: Intersections]
Happy face = intersection not detected - distance < radius, Sad face = intersection detected - distance > radius.
Yellow zone edge is mine line segment. As you can see it works when the intersection is on the top(/bottom), but not on the left(/right) side. 
That's my calculation algorithm calculating distance from line segment to point. Forgive the mess... I'm still struggling with that, so it's not optimized yet:

```
public static double pointLineSegmentDistance(final List<Double> point, final List<List<Double>> line)
{
    List<Double> v = line.get(0);
    List<Double> w = line.get(1);
    double d = pointPointSquaredDistance(v, w);
    double t;
    List<Double> calculateThis;
    if (d > 0)
    {
        boolean test = (t = ((point.get(0) - v.get(0)) * (w.get(0) - v.get(0)) + (point.get(1) - v.get(1)) * (w.get(1) - v.get(1))) / d) < 0;
        if (test)
        {
            calculateThis = v;
        }
        else
        {
            if (t > 1)
            {
                calculateThis = w;
            }
            else
            {
                calculateThis = new ArrayList<Double>();
                calculateThis.add(v.get(0) + t * (w.get(0) - v.get(0)));
                calculateThis.add(v.get(1) + t * (w.get(1) - v.get(1)));
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        calculateThis = v;
    }
    return Math.sqrt(pointPointSquaredDistance(point, calculateThis));
}

public static double pointPointSquaredDistance(final List<Double> v, final List<Double> w)
{
    double dx = v.get(0) - w.get(0);
    double dy = v.get(1) - w.get(1);
    return dx * dx + dy * dy;
}
```

final List point - contains 2 elements - (0) latitude (1) longitude
List> line - contains 2 lists - (0) line segment start point (0/0)lat/(0/1)long (1) line segment end point (1/0)lat/(1/1)long

Comment: That distance value is in which unit?

Comment: That's an accuracy from Location class. It says it is in meters.

Comment: ??? You said it was a distance and that you calculated it. And if it is from a location class then show how you get it. If you calculate it then show your calculation. Such an accuracy in meters is impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I've solved my problem. It comes the solution is really very simple. Much simpler than I thought. There's maputil library available here:
https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils

That library privides a function named "isLocationOnPath":

```
boolean isLocationOnPath(LatLng point, List<LatLng> polyline, boolean geodesic, double tolerance)
```

Point - is a center or my point. 
Polyline - for my needs is an edge of a polygon,
Geodesic - true (of course)
Tolerance - (in meters) is my accuracy taken from GPS accuracy - basicaly is a circle radius.

Details about the method:
http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/PolyUtil.html#isLocationOnPath-LatLng-java.util.List-boolean-

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have two possibilities:

1) The cheap way:

You calcualte the distances between line start/end point and circle center with the android api (distanceBetween()). The result will be in meters, and correctby means of point to point distance calculation. Take the minimum of both start / end point to center circle distances.
If the line segment is very long related to the circle radius, the normal distance of the line to center, using this kind of caluclation is wrong

2) The better way, but more complex:
You transform the line start and end and the circle center to cartesian x,y space with unit = meter and calculate the distance to the line 
segment using cartesian math. (see distance to line segment calculation)

First check option1 because it is just one line of code.

Your result of 0.00987506668990474 this looks like a distance in degrees, instead of meters. multiply it with 111km gives a value of about 1km. (at equator)

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use option 1. Circle radius always will stay between 5-20 meters but the line segments usually have about 1 - 2 kilometers.

Using option 2... gave me quite good results... but... I'm pretty sure I've missed something in the calculations. It works almost perfect when circle touches the line on top or bottom. The problem is on both left and right sides of the circle. The line cuts the circle in ~20-30% bettween circle edge and circle center. I'll update the question shortly and I'll attach screenshots to show how it looks. I'll attach my calculation algorithm as well.

Comment: Do you transform your coordinates to cartesian space?

Comment: Hmm.. I do not know what you're talking about... so it seems not. 
ps. question updated.

Comment: What is the unit of your coordinates? screen pixels? latitue longitude? Latitude longitude are spherical coordinates, this is not a plane x,y with equididstanc units. You cannot use just planar math, like you have learned in school. Either you know exactly what is allowed and what not, or transform first to cartesian space. Distacne calculation sdo not work, a booelan whether two lines intersect wozuld work.

Comment: I get my coordinates from android's location provider and they are latitude/longitude. Planar math (even 3d) is still clear to me, but... that problems I'm facing here is a bit too much for me. I'm reading really a lot about that now hoping I'll find something useful. But ... I'm getting impression it can be done easier than calculating distances. For now.. I do not understand how to transform that to cartesian space and how it could help.

Comment: If you are able to solve the problem with planar math, similar to school, you have to transform first, this is probably your only chance. Use a Equirectangular projection with center coordinate = center of circle. Multiply with meters per degree = 40.000 000 / 360.0